# How do I create a formula for the total number of stat points per level?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Cutting to the chase. I’m trying to create a formula to translate a certain sequence for the total amount of stat points per level in a rpg I’m making. For every level, you gain a base of 5 stat points, with every tenth level increasing this by an additional 5 points.

For this sequence, it goes from level 9,10,11, and 12. This would be translated to 45, 50, 60, 70, with each number being the total unallocated stat points for each level.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0kjc3c5x1i)?

Comment: Yes exactly that. Much appreciated.